# 2 setTimeouts not clearing correctly - How to reset the proper way?

Tags: javascript

Will try to explain what I'm trying to do here. I have 2 logos and i want toggle 1 class after every setTimeout function `"show"` For some reason resetting the timeOut is not working properly.

The first function is fired after 5 seconds and the second function is fired after 8 seconds. I want to reset these because I don't want the function to be fired before the correct "X" amount of seconds is done.

```
let logo1 = document.querySelector('.logo-1');
let logo2 = document.querySelector('.logo-2');

function firstLogo() {
    console.log('First logo');
    logo1.classList.add('show');
    logo2.classList.remove('show');
    setTimeout(firstLogo, 5000);
}

function secondLogo() {
    console.log('Second logo');
    logo1.classList.remove('show');
    logo2.classList.add('show');
    setTimeout(secondLogo, 8000);
}

setTimeout(firstLogo, 8000);
setTimeout(secondLogo, 5000);
```

Can someone help?

Comment: @hussain.codes where should I put it?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't you looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead?

Comment: @hussain.codes— *setTimeout* only runs once, so nothing to clear once it's run.

Comment: One of these will run every 5 seconds, the other every 8 seconds (roughly) so there will be some strange interactions as they progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

The `clearTimeout` will prevent the function set with the setTimeout() to execute.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You will get some strange interactions between the timeouts, e.g.

1. At the start, timers will be set for 5 and 8 seconds
2. At 5 seconds:

   1. logo1 will be shown
   2. logo 2 will be hidden
   3. the function will run in another 5 seconds
3. At 8 seconds:

   1. logo 2 will be shown
   2. logo 1 will be hidden
   3. the function is set to run again in 8 seconds
4. At 10 seconds, the first function runs again so logo 1 is shown
5. At 15 seconds, the first function runs again, logo 1 is alreay shown
6. At 16 seconds, the second function runs again, logo 2 is shown
7. At 20 seconds, the first function runs again, logo 1 is shown
8. At 24 second, the second function runs again, logo 2 is shown
9. At 25 seconds, the first function runs again, logo 1 is shown
10. At 30 seconds, the first function runs again, logo 1 is alreay shown
11. At 32 second, the second function runs again, logo 2 is shown
12. and so on…

Perhaps you want logo 2 shown for 5 seconds, then logo 1 for 3 seconds, then logo 2 for 5 seconds, etc.

In that case, you can call one function from the other, using appropriate settings for *setTimeout*. Since the default is to display the logos, I've changed *show* to *hide*, e.g.

```js
let logo1 = document.querySelector('.logo-1');
let logo2 = document.querySelector('.logo-2');

function firstLogo() {
    console.log('Hiding first logo');
    logo1.classList.toggle('hide');
    logo2.classList.toggle('hide');
    setTimeout(secondLogo, 3000);
}

function secondLogo() {
    console.log('Hiding second logo');
    logo1.classList.toggle('hide');
    logo2.classList.toggle('hide');
    setTimeout(firstLogo, 5000);
}

firstLogo();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="logo-1">logo 1</span><span class="logo-2 hide">logo 2</span>
```